# How can i change default user of ADB daemon

Tags: adb

When i use `adb shell` i am logged in as user `shell` who is in lot of groups and have a lot of permissions. My question is if i can change default user which ADB daemon use to have less permissions. For example to use application user. Is this possible without rooting device?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? Misuse of adb is near impossible if the device is protected by some lock screen and programs can't get access to shell user's privileges without explicit authorisation by the user.

Comment: I am using ADB over TCP and i need it because of security reasons.

Comment: You need to modify adb daemon source code and recompile. See this: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/system/core/adb/daemon/main.cpp#126 But might be you can drop some groups `shell` user is member of by modifying files `/system/etc/permissions/*platform.xml`. See this: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/data/etc/platform.xml#139 You can also consider using ssh for dropped privileges. With root, you will be able to get desired groups and capabilities from remote shell.